# How to include an optional library key in a solution for a .net application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, licensing, solution, license-key

I'm using a commercial library bought with my companies funds to build a WPF application for a customer.  The customer is getting periodic code drops (as insurance on their part in case something happens to my employer).

The commercial library is available via nuget (so I don't need to protect binaries) and activated via a license key (without one being provided it watermarks as a trial version).

To minimize the risk of accidentally (reverse engineering from binaries/etc is not part of our threat model) giving the key to the customer I want a way to store it in a separate file that can be excluded from the code drops.  If present it also needs to be embedded in the binaries and not eg loaded from a config file at runtime in the delivered application.

Is there anything built into Visual Studio solutions or project files that would support this?

Comment: What do you mean by "can be excluded from the code drops"?

Comment: @EduardMalakhov when we send the next (weeklyish) delivery of source code to the customer the key needs to not be in the delivery.  If it was a web application running on a server we controlled I'd just have it load a keyfile at runtime and then have my ignore file for the customers source control exclude the file when committing the code delivery.  But since this is a desktop app loading from a text file at startup isn't an option.